# SwiftUI - Animating a state variable that reloads a view causes it to breifly fade out and back in

Tags: swiftui

I would like to show a bunch of vertical bars, and on the click of a button have the first one swap places with a randomly selected one. I want this to be animated and the gif below shows the closest I've come, but as you can see, **the entire set of vertical bars flashes briefly on each button click**, which I do not want.

[image: View Swap Animation]

I've tried a few different approaches. The most elegant one I think would be to have the array of values which I iterate through to show the bars be a state variable, and when the array is sorted, the list just reloads and the swapping is animated. However, this didn't result in a swapping effect. It would just shrink and grow the respective bars to match the sizes of the array elements that were swapped :( I still feel like this might be the best approach, so I'm open to completely changing the implementation.

So the closest I've come is what you see in the gif, but it's hacky and I don't like the flashing of the entire view when it reloads. I'm using matchedGeometryEffect (hero animation) and even to get that working, I had to have a state variable that would reload the view. As you will see in the code below, this forces me to have an if/else even if I am just reloading the view under either condition. So I don't truly need the if(animate){} else {}, but using a hero animation forces me to.

Here's my code:

```
import SwiftUI

class SortElement: Identifiable{
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var color: Color
    var height: CGFloat

    init(id: Int, name: String, color: Color, height: CGFloat){
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
        self.height = height
    }
}

struct SortArrayAnimationDemo: View {
    @Namespace private var animationSwap
    @State private var animate: Bool = false

    private static var sortableElements: [SortElement] = [
        SortElement(id: 6, name:"6", color: Color(UIColor.lightGray), height: 60),
        SortElement(id: 2, name:"2", color: Color(UIColor.lightGray), height: 20),
        SortElement(id: 5, name:"5", color: Color(UIColor.lightGray), height: 50),
        SortElement(id: 1, name:"1", color: Color(UIColor.lightGray), height: 10),
        SortElement(id: 3, name:"3", color: Color(UIColor.lightGray), height: 30),
        SortElement(id: 9, name:"9", color: Color(UIColor.lightGray), height: 90),
        SortElement(id: 4, name:"4", color: Color(UIColor.lightGray), height: 40),
        SortElement(id: 8, name:"8", color: Color(UIColor.lightGray), height: 80)
    ]

    var body: some View {

        VStack{

            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0)
                .fill(Color.blue)
                .frame(width: 200.0, height: 20.0)

            if(animate){
                fetchSwappingView()
            }else {
                fetchSwappingView()
            }

            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0)
                .fill(Color.blue)
                .frame(width: 200.0, height: 20.0)

            Button(action: { doAnimate() }) { Text("Swap!") }.padding(.top, 30)

        }//vstack
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    private func fetchSwappingView() -> some View {

        HStack(alignment: .bottom){
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0)
                .fill(Color.red)
                .frame(width: 30.0, height: 100.0)

            ForEach(0..<SortArrayAnimationDemo.sortableElements.count) { i in

                let sortableElement = SortArrayAnimationDemo.sortableElements[i]

                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0)
                    .fill(Color.gray)
                    .frame(width: 20.0, height: sortableElement.height)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: sortableElement.id,
                                   in: animationSwap,
                                   properties: .position)
            }

            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0)

                .fill(Color.red)

                .frame(width: 30.0, height: 100.0)

        }//hstack

    }

    private func doAnimate() -> Void {
        let randomIndex = Int.random(in: 1..<8)
        let tmpLeftSortableElement: SortElement = SortArrayAnimationDemo.sortableElements[0]

        SortArrayAnimationDemo.sortableElements[0] = SortArrayAnimationDemo.sortableElements[randomIndex]

        SortArrayAnimationDemo.sortableElements[randomIndex] = tmpLeftSortableElement

        withAnimation(.spring(dampingFraction: 0.7).speed(1.5).delay(0.05)){

            animate.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I edited the title to be more descriptive, but it wouldn't let me edit the body because it said somebody else already did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a couple problems. First, you're working around the immutability of `struct`s with this:

```
private static var sortableElements: [SortElement] = [
```

`static` isn't going to make SwiftUI refresh the view. I think you found this out too, so added another `@State`:

```
@State private var animate: Bool = false

...

if (animate) {
    fetchSwappingView()
} else {
    fetchSwappingView()
}
```

Well... this is where your flashing is coming from. The default [`transition`](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-and-remove-views-with-a-transition) applied to an if-else is a simple fade, which is what you're seeing.

But, if you think about it, this if-else doesn't make any sense. There's no need for an intermediary `animate` state — just let SwiftUI do the work!

You were initially on the right track.

> The most elegant one I think would be to have the array of values which I iterate through to show the bars be a state variable, and when the array is sorted, the list just reloads and the swapping is animated. However, **this didn't result in a swapping effect. It would just shrink and grow the respective bars to match the sizes of the array elements that were swapped :(** I still feel like this might be the best approach, so I'm open to completely changing the implementation.

---

As you thought, the better way would be to just have a single `@State` array of `SortElement`s. I'll get to the swapping effect problem in a bit — first, replace `private static var` with `@State private var`:

```
@State private var sortableElements: [SortElement] = [
```

This makes it possible to directly modify `sortableElements`. Now, in your `doAnimate` function, just set `sortableElements` instead of doing all sorts of weird stuff.

```
private func doAnimate() -> Void {
    let randomIndex = Int.random(in: 1..<8)
    let tmpLeftSortableElement: SortElement = sortableElements[0]

    withAnimation(.spring(dampingFraction: 0.7).speed(1.5).delay(0.05)){
        sortableElements[0] = sortableElements[randomIndex]
        sortableElements[randomIndex] = tmpLeftSortableElement
    }
}
```

Don't forget to also replace

```
if (animate) {
    fetchSwappingView()
} else {
    fetchSwappingView()
}
```

with:

```
fetchSwappingView()
```

At this point, your result should look like this:

[image: Heights change, but no swap animation]

This matches your problem description: the heights change fine, but there's no animation!

> this didn't result in a swapping effect. It would just shrink and grow the respective bars to match the sizes of the array elements that were swapped :(

The problem is here:

```
ForEach(0..<sortableElements.count) { i in
```

Since you're simply looping over `sortableElements.count`, SwiftUI has no idea how the order changed. Instead, you should directly loop over `sortableElements`. The array's elements, `SortElement`, all conform to `Identifiable` — so SwiftUI can now [determine how the order changed](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/working-with-identifiable-items-in-swiftui).

```
ForEach(sortableElements) { element in
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0)
        .fill(Color.gray)
        .frame(width: 20.0, height: element.height)
        .matchedGeometryEffect(
            id: element.id,
            in: animationSwap,
            properties: .position
        )
}
```

Here's the final code:

```
struct SortArrayAnimationDemo: View {
    @Namespace private var animationSwap
    
    @State private var sortableElements: [SortElement] = [
        SortElement(id: 6, name:"6", color: Color(UIColor.lightGray), height: 60),
        SortElement(id: 2, name:"2", color: Color(UIColor.lightGray), height: 20),
        SortElement(id: 5, name:"5", color: Color(UIColor.lightGray), height: 50),
        SortElement(id: 1, name:"1", color: Color(UIColor.lightGray), height: 10),
        SortElement(id: 3, name:"3", color: Color(UIColor.lightGray), height: 30),
        SortElement(id: 9, name:"9", color: Color(UIColor.lightGray), height: 90),
        SortElement(id: 4, name:"4", color: Color(UIColor.lightGray), height: 40),
        SortElement(id: 8, name:"8", color: Color(UIColor.lightGray), height: 80)
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0)
                .fill(Color.blue)
                .frame(width: 200.0, height: 20.0)
            
            fetchSwappingView() /// NO if else needed!
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0)
                .fill(Color.blue)
                .frame(width: 200.0, height: 20.0)
            
            Button(action: { doAnimate() }) { Text("Swap!") }.padding(.top, 30)
            
        }//vstack
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    private func fetchSwappingView() -> some View {
        
        HStack(alignment: .bottom){
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0)
                .fill(Color.red)
                .frame(width: 30.0, height: 100.0)
            
            /// directly loop over `sortableElements` instead of its count
            ForEach(sortableElements) { element in
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0)
                    .fill(Color.gray)
                    .frame(width: 20.0, height: element.height)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(
                        id: element.id,
                        in: animationSwap,
                        properties: .position
                    )
            }
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0)
                .fill(Color.red)
                .frame(width: 30.0, height: 100.0)
            
        }//hstack
        
    }
    
    private func doAnimate() -> Void {
        let randomIndex = Int.random(in: 1..<8)
        let tmpLeftSortableElement: SortElement = sortableElements[0]
        
        /// directly set `sortableElements`
        withAnimation(.spring(dampingFraction: 0.7).speed(1.5).delay(0.05)){
            sortableElements[0] = sortableElements[randomIndex]
            sortableElements[randomIndex] = tmpLeftSortableElement
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Heights change with swap animation]

Comment: Ah! I knew it was something simple that I was missing. I searched for days for an explanation to the flashing effect and found nothing, so I hope this post helps others. I'll try this out and if it all works, I'll come back and mark this as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks again!